# How to import Alexa skill into API.AI / Dialogflow?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to export my Alexa Skill / import it into Dialogflow (used to be called API.AI), but I'm getting the following error message:

`Invalid Alexa schema json file.`

My Zip file is the index.js file and the node_modules folder zipped together.  Then I added the Alexa Skill JSON named schema.json to the zip too, but it still gives the same error.

I cannot find instructions on how to export the correct Alexa .zip for import, nor how to format the zip to build it myself.  I've been searching for a while -- does anyone know how to do this?  (I emailed their support already, but no response yet.)

Answer (score 1):

There were some updates to the Alexa Interaction Model, so the Dialogflow Alexa Importer doesn't seem to work anymore.

There are a few things to consider when porting an Alexa Model into a Dialogflow Agent:

- Built-in Intents: You need to create custom Dialogflow intents for built-in Alexa intents like `AMAZON.HelpIntent`
- Built-in Slots: Amazon offers a large variety of slots (e.g. `AMAZON.Number`) that need to be converted to Dialogflow. For this, Dialogflow offers System Entities. [Find all System Entities here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/system-entities).

I created a complete step by step guide and video that uses the [Jovo Language Model](https://www.jovo.tech/docs/model) to translate an Alexa Model into a Dialogflow Agent. You can find it here: [Tutorial: Turn an Alexa Interaction Model into a Dialogflow Agent](https://www.jovo.tech/tutorials/alexa-model-to-dialogflow).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of the format for the zip: https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-importer-nodejs/tree/master/skill/speechAssets

The zip should have two files: `IntentSchema.json` and `SampleUtterances.txt`

Here is how to get `IntentSchema.json` and `SampleUtterances.txt`:
Go to https://developer.amazon.com/edw/home.html#/skills to view all your skills.
Select the skill you'd like to export to by clicking on the skill name for the corresponding skill:
[image]
On the left select "Interaction Model" from the list and you should see the screenshot below:
[image]
Copy the contents of the the editor and paste it into your IntentSchema.json file and save it.
Next, copy the contents into the editor of the "Sample Utterances" section and paste into your SampleUtterances.txt file and save:
[image]
Lastly zip up your IntentSchema.json and SampleUtterances.txt files and upload them to Dialogflow

Comment: I appreciate the help, but when I try to upload the zip with just those two files I'm getting a small pop-up saying `File speechAssets.zip was not uploaded.`  No more details than that.

Comment: Have you tried using the zip in the sample? https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-importer-nodejs/blob/master/skill/speechAssets/speechAssets.zip

Comment: @matthewayne Do DialogFlow supports Dialog Directives of Alexa Skill?

Comment: I have the same issue. Also, the screenshot shown above showing the interaction model is not correct. The actual schema in the new interaction model beta is much different.

Comment: The Alexa importer has been broken for over a year. And you always get the same error "xxxx.zip"was not uploaded. Can't believe that Google owns this and does nothing about it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if your still working on this but if anyone else is stuck, the files you zip have to read `IntentSchema.json` and `SampleUtterances.txt` exactly.

Comment: The Alexa importer has been broken for over a year. And you always get the same error "xxxx.zip"was not uploaded. Can't believe that Google owns this and does nothing about it.