# Can't import Alexa Skill into Dialogflow

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to import an Alexa Skill into Dialogflow following [the official tutorial](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/alexa-importer) without success.

It always gives me an unknown error:

> Unknown error errorid=6e103e65-18cc-465c-ab1a-6915c25a1169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Alexa Import is broken, as [an issue](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-importer-nodejs/issues/1) in the official tutorial repository points out:

> Alexa version is updated.
>
> It now exports only one json file, merging all the training phrases
>   and actions into one. So I am not able to use the plugin (under
>   dialogflow-> integrations-> alexa). I have already reported this to
>   support team few weeks back, please let me know if we have any update
>   on this.
>   3
>
> The top SO answer is also of no help, as some commenters point out, as
>   it's for the old method:
>   [How to import Alexa skill into API.AI / Dialogflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748429/how-to-import-alexa-skill-into-api-ai-dialogflow#46777623)
>
> It seems like Alexa Import is entirely broken at this point.

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm unable to use integration Diagloflow-> Alexa

Comment: Just an FYI, this is still an issue though via the Dailogflow console, you now just get an "Error" notification with no further info.